# How to pass @valid exceptions to AngularJS service so that it can be displayed at view page?

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, spring-boot, web

Using AngularJS and SpringBoot so sending a post from Angular service.js to springboot controller

```
               $http.post(urls.USER_SERVICE_API, user)
                    .then(
                        function (response) {                           
                            deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        },
                        function (errResponse) {
                           console.error('Error while creating User : '+errResponse.data.errorMessage);
                           deferred.reject(errResponse);
                        }
                    );
```

And Springboot controller-

```
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder, BindingResult result)
```

Problem is whenever request comes to rest controller, it goes to validate in custom validator and after that there is no error coming back to AngularJS service, so what is missed here. I can see all exeptions and messages printing on the console but it only come back to serviceJS with only status code of 400.

Answer (score 0):

`@NotNull(message = "name is a required field")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 40, message = "name cannot be longer than 40 char")
    private String name;`

Try giving proper message. please share some more code from validation bean class for specific solution.